# Magento 2.1.1 - product import error - looking for solution

Tags: magento2, importexport

csv file checks out perfectly, no errors, but I get:

> General system exception happened Additional data: Notice: Undefined
>   index: in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Ampps\www\jblattert\magento2\vendor\magento\module-cat‌​alog-import-export\M‌​odel\Import\Product\‌​Type\AbstractType.ph‌​p
>   on line 496

I see this in reply of another post, but don't know where to start to correct. Additionally, I deleted all unused attributes (from sample data) that were Multiple Select. There are now no multiple select attributes. Problem still occurs.

*This occurs when your input attribute is a one-to-one relationship in the database. You set this up when you setup the Attribute - you need to choose Multiple Select for multiple values to work. The column value such as red|blue|green is taken whole and Magento kicks this out because as a whole, "red|blue|green" is not a valid column value. Change your product attribute so it can take multiple values.*

Comment: I am facing the same issue.